# Get n number of random records using nested serializers Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to get random 'n' number of records from foreign key related models. Suppose I have two models named `Exam` and `Questions`. I need an API endpoint to get n number of questions for one particular subject(ex. for math, n random math questions). The endpoint is working well in retrieving all the questions for a particular subject.

**models.py**

```
class Exam(models.Model):
   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.question)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    questions = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    answer = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'


class ExamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='question_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = '__all__'
```

**api_views.py**

```
class ExamQuestionRetrieveAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    authentication_classes = [JWTTokenUserAuthentication]

    serializer_class = ExamSerializer
    queryset = Exam.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'name'
```

After going through the doc, I tried to filter and get random records using the [`to_representation()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) method but failed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `queryset = Exam.objects.all('?')` and you can use pagination to select only `n` items.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, I had that idea too :) but it can expose all the questions.

Comment: that is what the pagination is about, or you can limit it by overriding the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: For question model... have to look into that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want N random questions of 1 exam, I would do the following:

- Create a custom action in a Viewset (or a custom view)

  - It should be a DETAIL model action, meaning it looks like `exams/3/your-action-name/`
  - It should be a GET request
- Then implement the following logic:

  - Fetch the exam model
  - Then fetch the Questions for that exam using `"?"` to order them randomly and only take a few
  - Then serialize the question instances
  - And return the data

Here's what it could look like:

```py
def get_random_questions(self, request, pk=None):
    exam = self.get_object()
    questions = Question.objects.filter(exam=exam).order_by("?")[:5] # Update with your desired number
    serializer = QuestionSerializer(questions, many=True)
    return Reponse(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way without changing the implementation, the previous attempt to use `to_representation()` was done in the wrong serializer. Anyway able to return 'n'  random records by using [`np.random.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) here's how I did it. In `Question` serializer,

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super().to_representation(instance)
    representation['questions'] = np.random.choice(
         representation['questions'],
         10, # n(=10) number of records
         replace=False
    )

    return representation
```

But, using the `to_representation()` means all the question objects will be loaded and then from that list, `np.random.choice()` will get n number of random records. Which is not so cool.

---

So it seemed that the **@Jordan** answer was much more convenient so I used `APIView` instead of `generics.RetrieveAPIView` and without using nested serialization.

```
class ExamQuestionAPIView(APIView):

    def get_object(self, name):
        try:
            return Quiz.objects.get(name=name)
        except Quiz.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, name, format=None):
        """
            Return 10 random questions.
        """

        questions = QuizQuestion.objects.filter(
            quiz=self.get_object(name)
        ).order_by('?')[:10]

        questions_serialized = QuizQuestionSerializer(questions, many=True)

        return Response(questions_serialized.data)
```